# Moving an object without animating it in an animation block

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I'm animating a bunch of buttons so they move to the left of the screen then they should magically move to the right of the screen. I do this by calling:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.20 target:self selector:@selector(moveTheButtons) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

in viewDidLoad.

They animate quite happily to the left, but then they animate back to the right. I just want them to disappear and reappear to the right-off-screen. Because I'm new I assumed that since it was after the commitAnimations call that it wouldn't animate. I think the problem is that the animations actually 'commit' after the moveTheButtons function returns, but I can't think of an elegant (or standard) way around this.

**How do I move the UIButton off screen without animating it, preferably still in the moveTheButtons function?**

As you can probably infer, I'm new to animations on the iPhone, so if you see any other mistakes I'm making feel free to give me some pointers.

```
-(void)moveTheButtons{
NSLog(@"moveTheButtons");

[UIView beginAnimations:@"mov-ey" context:cloudA];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: .20];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
cloudA.center = CGPointMake(cloudA.center.x-pos.x,cloudA.center.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];


if(cloudA.center.x < -100){
    //I don't want to animate this bit. 
    cloudA.center = CGPointMake(550,cloudA.center.y);
}

//NSLog(@"cloudA.center.x %f", cloudA.center.x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precalculate the point , invert the order and return before animating the block.

You are unconditionally committing an animation to the engine in all cases.

```
-(void)moveTheButtons{
NSLog(@"moveTheButtons");

CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(cloudA.center.x-pos.x,cloudA.center.y);

if(cloudA.center.x < -100){
    //I don't want to animate this bit. 
    cloudA.center = CGPointMake(550,cloudA.center.y);
    return;
}


[UIView beginAnimations:@"mov-ey" context:cloudA];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: .20];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
cloudA.center = mypoint;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Theres a style point about using a return rather than if/else but you can form your own opinion.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily turn off the implicit animations of properties within an animation block using the `+[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:]` method. This can be very useful in many use cases.

Do something like this:

```
-(void)moveTheButtons {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: .20];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(cloudA.center.x - pos.x, cloudA.center.y);
    if (center.x < -100) {
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
        cloudA.center = CGPointMake(550, center.y);
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        cloudA.center = center;
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

As a side note; there is no need to give the animation a name, or a context, unless you actually use a delegate that responds to delegate methods. Just pass `nil`, and `NULL` as I have done in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about context and name! Warren answered first, so he gets the correct tick, but I really appreciate your answer and suggestion.